# How do I integrate my app with a company phone on WhatsApp Business API?

Tags: facebook, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

Our company created an app that allows you to receive notifications through the WhatsApp Business webhook and send messages through it (API), using the test phone and test token provided by Facebook.

The problem now is to link a real phone, the business page with our app, so we can get the real token for each phone and identifiers.

We tried using the classic FB.login, which lists pages from Facebook, Instagram, Messenger, etc., and listing WhatsApp accounts linked to a business page, but there is nothing that allows us to obtain the token and IDs from these WhatsApp Business registrations.

As Facebook's documentation is very confusing at this point, can we only make this link
(between business page and app), if we use Embedded Signup or is there another way?

Comment: Need to clarify your question. What is "my app"? which app are you talking about? Second, let me clarify this, the WhatsApp Business API is only for businesses, so only businesses who have valid and verified businesses can use WhatsApp Business API and add their mobile no.